# Pycharm and indexing TexLive2022 while using TeXiFy IDEA

Tags: indexing, pycharm

I have installed `PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Community Edition)` and the `TeXiFy IDEA`. Then the system stares indexing my `TeXLive2022` directory but hang somewhere during the, i.e. indexing will be never finished. Also the point, where the process stops is always at different files. I deinstalled `TeXiFy IDEA` and then everything works well.

Is this a known problem or bug? And what to do? The suggestions I found will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed by the owner of the plugin to delete the package `wargame` in my TeXLive installation. Indeed, this was the solution. Indexing was fast and ok.